# How to get JSON Object using Retrofit for Android

Tags: android, django-rest-framework, retrofit2

I'm using Android and DRF, Retrofit now.

I'm trying to get Django models using Retrofit, It returns JSON Response.

But in my model, there is multiple JSON Objects.

For example,

request url is [object1's url]

and

response =
{
object2:[object2's url],
some other data(s)
}

How can I change object2 to json object using Retrofit?

---

Edit

I solved this issue using multiple AsyncTask.
get Object1 and object2's url, and in onPostExecute, make some new AsyncTask, get Object2 by Retrofit, check Object2's url and Object2's list parameter 'url' and match.
for example,

```
AsyncTask() {
  doInBackground() {
    get object1List
  }
  onPostExecute(object1List) {
    AsyncTask2() {
      doInBackground() {
        get object2List
        for (object1 : object1List)
          object2ListItem & object1.url match
      }
      onPostExecute() {
        something to do
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can get from server raw answer and use GSON library to parse it - https://github.com/google/gson.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to receive the raw JSON and then parsing with GSON

```
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().setLenient().create();

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)) 
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

and create a class where got the expected information example

```
public class People{
    @Expose
    private String Name;
    @Expose
    private Int Age;
    @Expose
    private String Surname;

// setters and getters...
```

the api interface

```
public interface APIService {
 @POST("people.php")
    Call<whatyoureceive> response();

}
```

Also

```
private static final String BASE_URL = "YOUR URL";

public static APIService getAPIService() {

    return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(APIService.class);
}
```

In your activity

```
private APIService mAPIService;

mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();



public void sendRequest() {
        mAPIService.responseo().enqueue(new Callback<PlanDetails>() {
@Override
            public void onResponse(......) {
// what you want to do
}
@Override
            public void onFailure(.....) {
// what you want to do
}
```

More information https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

Hope help!